# Help translating

Tags: translation

Not sure this is the correct forum for this post as I'm not a student, but I need help translating this a error message I keep getting. I'm hoping it's Chinese. 
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10264776/Screen%20Shot%202013-01-25%20at%207.54.42%20PM.png
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Chinese Language and Usage Beta! As per the [FAQ], we do not forbid translation requests but note that **this is not a translation service**, so we will close any translation request that does not show research effort. You must make sure you clearly show it in your question if you want to avoid the closure. Note that you can edit your question and improve it by using the "edit" button below it.

Comment: -1 for no research effort per Alenanno. It's a forum for learners of Chinese, not for someone who simply wants a Chinese phrase translated. Just for future reference, you can try here next time: en.wiktionary.org/wiki/WT:TRREQ . This is monitored by most administrators.

Comment: Hello user2458, I'm closing this question for lack of response. *But*... you can still improve it! Just click the `edit` button. When you're done, click **flag** and choose **custom** and write "I improved my qustion". A moderator will check it and reopen it. :) (Note: a -1 is automatic.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The installed program has already determined your configuration doesn't support any accessories"

Comment: I'd probably translate 附带产品 into *accessories*, but that's just me.

Comment: @JamesJiao Good point. Edited.